# how can I create a migration to add a value to an enum in eloquent

Tags: laravel, enums, eloquent

I have a table that contains an enum field

```
CREATE TABLE `user_status` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `values` enum('on', 'off'),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

how can I create a migration to add a value to the enum field?

Comment: The doctrine docs have something to say about ENUMs and why they are not so good supported: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/mysql-enums.html

Answer (score 74):

Laravel doesn't provide methods to update an enum column. You can delete and recreate the column but you could loose data during the operation and it's not really *clean*.

In this case, I think that the best choice is to write raw SQL into a migration :

```php
public function up()
{
    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE user_status MODIFY COLUMN ENUM('on','off','unknown')");
}

public function down()
{
    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE user_status MODIFY COLUMN ENUM('on','off')");
}
```

*I could have made a mistake in the SQL syntax, I have never used `ENUM`, but you can see the idea anyway.*

Comment: Be aware that you can only support databases that support the ENUM type with this solution. For example, running tests with SQLite will break.

Comment: Is it still the "best" way to write raw SQL DDL if you have no idea what database platform the migration will be run on?

Comment: Any migration name convention for this?

Comment: Thanks for this. I put my column name at `COLUMN` the `values` part is causing a syntax error you could remove it.

Comment: Running "php artisan migrate" gives me "Nothing to migrate". Should I go for manual update in my localhost after updating here?

Comment: Just to add an advice in case someone else faces the problem I was facing: in case you try this solution and see an "_SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;_" your problem might be that the column name of the enum column that you're trying to update is one of the many **MySQL Keywords and Reserved Words** (more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html))

Answer (score 6):

I did it with MySql:

```
class ChangeJobTypeEnum extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE _TABLENAME_ CHANGE _COLUMNNAME_ _COLUMNNAME_ ENUM('on', 'off', 'auto')");

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE _TABLENAME_ CHANGE _COLUMNNAME_ _COLUMNNAME_ ENUM('on', 'off')");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a slightly different situation, it was necessary to add new items, change existing and remove old. This is my example.

```
 <?php

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class ChangeEnum extends Migration
{   
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('table_example', function (Blueprint $table) {
            DB::statement("ALTER TABLE table_example MODIFY status enum('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth') NOT NULL;");
            DB::statement("UPDATE `field` set `status` = 'fourth' where `status` = 'first';");
            DB::statement("UPDATE `field` set `status` = 'fifth' where `status` = 'second';");
            DB::statement("ALTER TABLE table_example MODIFY status enum('third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth') NOT NULL;");
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('table_example', function (Blueprint $table) {
            DB::statement("ALTER TABLE table_example MODIFY status enum('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth') NOT NULL;");
            DB::statement("UPDATE `field` set `status` = 'first' where `status` = 'fourth';");
            DB::statement("UPDATE `field` set `status` = 'second' where `status` = 'fifth';");
            DB::statement("ALTER TABLE table_example MODIFY status enum('first', 'second', 'third',) NOT NULL;");
        });
    }
}
```

By the way, generate row SQL query via JetBrains ide(DataGrip), is like that:

```
　∧＿∧ 
（｡･ω･｡)つ━☆・*。
⊂　　 ノ 　　　・゜+.
 しーＪ　　　°。+ *´¨)
```

Answer (score 1):

The second answer works, but in my case `CHANGE` was throwing an error. So i tried using `MODIFY` instead and that worked. Thanks guys..

Here is my code:

```
class ChangeJobTypeEnum extends Migration {

/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE _TABLENAME_ MODIFY _COLUMNNAME_ ENUM('on', 'off', 'auto')");

}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE _TABLENAME_ MODIFY_COLUMNNAME_ ENUM('on', 'off')");

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **I say**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('dt_warehouses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            **$table->enum('isactive', ['Y', 'N'])->default('Y');**
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```